# Blacklist the "connection" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

What kind of [connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connection)? Internet connection? USB connection? Asdfghjkl connection? It should be blacklisted, I think.

Comment: MM... I only see a question or two every few days, shouldn't we able to remove it manually since they are still below the 500?